# How can I develop and test part of an Outlook Add-In without opening Outlook all the time?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I am in the process to develop my first Outlook Add-In in C# in Visual Studio.

When I want to test my unfinished program I have to close Outlook (if it is open). Then I press F5 (Start Debugging), Outlook will be opened, the unfinished Add-In will be loaded and I can test it in Outlook. Then I close it again and add new functionality.

All this makes sense. Expect for many of my methods I don't need Outlook. I.e. I extract information from strings and compare them with other stings, copy and move files, etc. If possible I would like to test these methods just in VS without Outlook opening. I could do this if I would create a separate project (no Add-In), do all the programming which is independent from Outlook, and then copy the files into my Outlook Add-In project. But this seems to me too complicated.

**Is there an easy way to test part of an Outlook Add-In without Outlook?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another project to your VS solution that uses the same source files but compiles into a standalone exe.

Comment: A perfect answer within two minutes. I tried it, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Unit Test project and call the desired functions from there.
This also has the added benefit of all your testing being in a desired location for independent repetitive testing.